# In first time it should launch with say activity A and from second time onwards it should always lanunch From activity B

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In first time it should launch with say activity A and from second time onwards it  should always lanunch  Activity B .Without Using shared preference is there any other way ..

Fist Time Launch ------>Activity A .From Second Time Onwards  it should Launch ----->Activity B .Not A.
Hope am clear ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First  Write a function to choose the Launcher screen .

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {

ChooseLauncherScreen();

}

void ChooseLauncherScreen()
{
       final    SharedPreferences StatusView= getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,                       MODE_PRIVATE);

boolean  Viewclas = StatusView.getBoolean("Statusval", false);

```
 if(Viewclas==false)
{


    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = StatusView.edit();          // 
    editor.putBoolean("Statusval", true);
    editor.commit();
    Bundle b3=new Bundle();
    b3.putString("PageFrom","FromScreen");

    Intent intent=new Intent(FromScreen.this,ToScreen.class).putExtras(b3);
    startActivity(intent);
    Yourclassname.this.finish();

}

else {
    //          
    ProceedtoApp();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add Preference in Your Application where you can save some parameter like `isFirstTime`. On the basis of Preference parameter you can redirect your user.

Here I'm fetched whether is `FirstTime` or not with the help of creating `Preferences` and  `getFirstTime()`.If its's already `FirstTime` setting that Preferences variable with `setFirstTime(true)`. I've have used reverse `FirstTime` in here.

`getFirstTime()` returns `false` if it's actually firstTime as Java default boolean values  is false. Then I set that parameter to `true`.

Code Snippet:

```
public class A extends Activity {
private Preferences appPrefs;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_a);
appPrefs = new Preferences(this);

}
if (!appPrefs.getFirstTime()) {
      Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
      appPrefs.setFirstTime(true);
      startActivity(i);
      finish();
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is you can only have one Activity with the MAIN intent-filter in the manifest. He's not starting from an existing Activity.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is give Activity B the `android.intent.action.MAIN` intent-filter in your AndroidManifest. Then, in Activity B's `onCreate()` you can check `SharedPreferences` for a boolean value. If it doesn't exist, set it in `SharedPreferences` and launch Activity A.

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean showActivityA = prefs.getBoolean("show_activity_A", true);
        if (showActivityA) {
            // don't show ActivityA on future launches
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("show_activity_A", false).apply();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Since Activity A will actually be on top of Activity B, pressing BACK will take the user to Activity B. All you have to do to navigate from A to B is call `finish()` in Activity A.